# Shiny : error when importing RData

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rdata

In the project I work on, I need to import a RData file.
This file contains several data.frame and a list. But I cant display data.frame.
Should somebody have an idea please ?

In fact, I need to have the same data than previous session, thats why I import a RData file.

Here is an example of what I would like to do.

**In global.R :**

```
## Package
library(shiny)

## Data Frame
data("iris")
data("mtcars")
data("Orange")

## Data
dfA <- iris
dfB <- mtcars
dfC <- Orange
init_ls <- list("a" = 1, "b" = LETTERS[c(5, 3)])

## Save
save(dfA, dfB, dfC, init_ls, file = "example.RData")

LoadToEnvironment <- function(file, env = new.env()) {
    load(file, env)
    return(env)
}
```

**In UI.R :**

```
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        ##===================================.
        ## UPLOAD
        ##===================================.
        sidebarLayout(
            ##-------------------.
            ## Side Bar : IMPORTATION
            ##-------------------.
            sidebarPanel(
                width = 4,
                fileInput(
                    inputId = "init_file",
                    label = "Init File (RData)",
                    accept = c(
                        "application/RData",
                        ".RData"
                    )
                )
            ),
            ##-------------------.
            ## Main : View Importation
            ##-------------------.
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    id = "tabset_upload",
                    tabPanel(title = "dfA",
                             tableOutput("dfA")),
                    tabPanel(title = "dfB",
                             tableOutput("dfB")),
                    tabPanel(title = "dfC",
                             tableOutput("dfC"))
                ) 
            )
            ##-------------------.
            ## end sideBar
            ##-------------------.
        )
    )
)
```

**In Server.R :**

I tried two ways to import .RData (ImportInit_1 et ImportInit_2)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    ##==============================================.
    ## Import
    ##==============================================.

    ImportInit_1 <- reactive({
        ## path
        path <- input$init_file
        if(is.null(path)){
            return(NULL)
        }else{
            env <- new.env()
            load(path, envir = env)
            return(env)
        }
    })

    ImportInit_2 <- reactive({
        ## path
        path <- input$init_file
        if(is.null(path)){
            return(NULL)
        }else{
            env <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, path, LoadToEnvironment)
            return(env)
        }
    })

    ##==============================================.
    ## OUTPUT DATA
    ##==============================================.
    ## Output dfTransit using "importTransit()"

    output$dfA <- renderTable(ImportInit_1()[["dfA"]])

    output$dfB <- renderTable(ImportInit_2()[["dfB"]])

    output$dfC <- renderTable(ImportInit_1()[["dfC"]])

})
```

The errors are :
ImportInit_1() --> "bad 'file' argument"
ImportInit_2() --> "invalid filename argument.

==> I dont understand why data are not displayed, knowing there are solutions I already found.

Thank you in advance to any one who could help me.

Ced